# Converting UIImage image representation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am getting an UIImage from UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext, but they are very heavyweight memory wise.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([self bounds].size);
// CGContext procedures
    _cacheImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

the size of the image is almost as the size of the iPad screen, (a little smaller), and when I  do something like this:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_cacheImage)
NSLog(@"%i", data.lenght);
```

It gives me like 700,000 in lenght. I'm guessing its a .7MB file?

Anyway if there is some way to reduce the image size, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to reduce quality, try using

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

Pass compressionQuality == 0.0 for maximum quality or compressionQuality == 1.0 for maximum compression.